# How to change the color of bold texts by changing index.css in Jupyter Lab?

Tags: css, themes, jupyter-lab

In Jupyter Lab, I just want to change the color of bold texts in the official light theme, just as a way of making simple highlights to avoid using HTML.
I've searched for several solutions but no one works for me.
The basic idea is to edit the index.css file, adding a code snippet like `strong {color: #xxxxxx;}`.
But the problem is there are more than one file named index.css exists, like `C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\themes\@jupyterlab\theme-light-extension\index.css`,  `C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\@jupyterlab\theme-light-extension\index.css`,  `C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\share\jupyter\lab\themes\@jupyterlab\theme-light-extension\index.css`.
I changed every one index.css mentioned above and failed in the end, so does anyone know what is the solution for now? Since I have little experience in CSS, so if I made some stupid mistakes, please let me know, thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some changes recently on my themes, so, according to my experience:

1. The file you must to modify is the one inside the "share" folder: `share\jupyter\lab\themes\@jupyterlab\theme-light-extension\index.css`
2. The only bold texts I found on my code mirror are marked as "Keywords" (i.e. `import`, `for`, `in`, `try`, `def`, etc)

If you want to change these bold text, you must to modify inside your `index.css` file the `--jp-mirror-editor-keyword-color` variable.